# .NET 6 returning view not found while it searches in the exact directory it is located in

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am working on a recent migration from a .NET 5 MVC app towards a .NET 6 MVC app with the new minimal hosting model. During this migration time and time again I hit the "View not found" InvalidOperationException.
Proof that the view is located in the right map and the program 'searched' for it in that location:
[image: the proof]

As you can see all the map and file names corospond.

I have followed the migration guide from Microsoft step by step but to no avail. Personally I think something is going wrong with adding in the endpoints but I have tried every single possible option .NET 6 gives me to add in the default controller route.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

or this

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

and ofcourse also this

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

but nothing works. I haven't really found any solutions online yet after googling, and this problem just makes it that I'm stuck with the migration. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hey, was the Razor RuntimeCompilation your final solution? It looks to come with some downsides such as not supporting hot reload
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue after updating my vs to 17.1.0. I installed the package`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` from NuGet.

Then at your Program.cs add reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` and the code below.

```
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Comment: Well this indeed solved it thank you! I had no idea we had to manually call upon the Razor runtime compilation again!